# What is the best way to to access custom OIDC attributes (claims) via Spring Security in a type safe way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect

We have a web application using OpenID Connect / Spring Security 5 to authenticate users.
Integration is really simple with the out-of-the-box OIDC support in Spring Security using the oauth2 authentication support (`oauth2Login`)

The Identity Provider exposes some attributes via the userInfo endpoint that we need a lot in our business logic (preferably in a type-safe way). These attributes are in some cases lists of rich objects, something difficult to access using a generic `Map<String,Object>`

The attributes from that userInfo endpoint are merged with the attributes from the id token in the default `OidcUserService`, and put on the `DefaultOidcUser` (so that it becomes part of the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`)

- `@AuthenticationPrincipal DefaultOidcUser defaultOidcUser` = a DefaultOidcUser that contains all of these attributes (using Maps)
- `java.security.Principal` = `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` (that in turn contains a principal, being our `DefaultOidcUser`)
- `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` = again the same `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`

So to access the custom attributes I can

1. cast the Principal (or SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())

```
public void doSomething(Principal principal) {
   OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken)principal;
   Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getPrincipal().getAttributes();
  ...
}
```

Downside here is I need to cast, and would need to convert the Map into a Pojo "somewhere" in the code, preferably only once.

2. Inject a `@AuthenticationPrincipal DefaultOidcUser` to avoid casting and access the attributes.

```
public void doSomething(@AuthenticationPrincipal DefaultOidcUser defaultOidcUser) {
    Map<String, Object> attributes = defaultOidcUser.getAttributes();
    ...

}
```

Here I don't need to cast, but still don't have the attributes as a pojo.

What would be the best way to have easy access to these attributes in a type-safe way ?

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-oauth2userservice) mentions the `OAuth2UserService`, where we have a hook to return a `OidcUser` that could be a custom object, exposing our attributes in a type safe way.

Leading me to option nr 3

3. Create a custom `oidcUserService`

```
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
        final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

        return (userRequest) -> {
            // Load original user
            OidcUser oidcUser = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

            // Parse custom claims
            CustomTypedAttributes customTypedAttributes = objectMapper.convertValue(oidcUser.getClaims(), CustomTypedAttributes.class);

            // Expose them as new custom user
            return new CustomOidcUser(oidcUser.getAuthorities(), oidcUser.getIdToken(), oidcUser.getUserInfo(), customTypedAttributes);
        };
    }
```

Advantage is we have type-safe access to our custom attributes, via `customOidcUser.getCustomTypedAttributes()`, they only need to be converted once (after login).

However, it doesn't feel "right" to wrap an `OidcUser` like this, just to expose a type safe attribute map.

Are there alternative ways of dealing with custom attributes in application code where the requirements are :

- Easy access to custom attributes in a type safe way
- Making use of the standard Spring Security building blocks
- Test-friendly (using spring security testing)

Comment: The solution you highlight for option 3 (using delegation to build a custom `OAuth2UserService`) is intended for cases such as yours, since it is mentioned explicitly in the documentation. I think it's a great solution. Why doesn't it feel "right" to you?

Comment: Not really sure. Perhaps the fact that I need to introduce a CustomOidcUser just for the sake of exposing the CustomTypedAttributes. Not really sure if OidcUser is a valid extension point. (The sample in the docs don't introduce a new subtype, just add some additional attributes). Put perhaps my concern is invalid

Comment: I wouldn't say invalid. But if I'm understanding your case, I think it's exactly the right extension point for you. If you think about the `UserDetailsService` as a similar (non-oauth2) abstraction, it's completely valid to sub-type `UserDetails`, in fact required because it's an interface. `OidcUser` is exactly the same type of thing for oauth2.

Comment: There are [techniques](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/b42984ef8bfb3c4934d74d4324a96e2f62d0e3be/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/user-details-service/custom-user/src/main/java/example/CustomUserRepositoryUserDetailsService.java#L48) for decoupling Spring Security from your domain model though.